# What setting affects implicit conversions?

Tags: sql-server

I have access to two databases, which are supposed to be a copy of each other.  On both there is a table named `GROUP` with a column `GROUP_INVOICE_NUMBER (varchar(20), not null)`.

On the first database I can execute:

```
select *
from GROUP
where GROUP_INVOICE_NUMBER = 4
```

which excecutes fine.  However on the second I get:

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Conversion failed when converting
>   the varchar value '1626CR2' to data type int.

I understand there must be a difference between the two database instances, and I'm guessing they are to do with implicit conversions and/or warning levels.

**Where do you think this difference is?**

Note:

I understand this is *awful* database design, however we've been lumbered with a legacy system which we are trying to improve (hence we need to create a test environment) where we are seeing this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is that the second database has data in the column that is not numeric and thus cannot do implict conversion at all.  You should not ever rely on implicit comnversion in any case. Either store teh data correctly or do an explict conversion.
This should work on both:

```
select *
from GROUP
where GROUP_INVOICE_NUMBER = '4'
```

Comment: I think you misread my question, both columns are `varchar(20), not null`

Comment: @m.edmondson, what does that have to do with it? Did you try the change suggested? You can't implicitly convert to int when the data in the column is not 100 percent convertable to an Int.

Comment: Both databases _should_ be the same, are you saying the data itself is different **not** the datatype that's causing this problem?  Putting single quotes on the 4 does work, but that isn't the question I'm asking.

Comment: Yes the data is differnt. In one db all the records could implicitly convert and in the other one they could not. That is why it is bad to rely on implicit conversion in any production code.

Comment: I understand now, and can confirm by replacing '4' with '1626CR2' I actually get a record back.  I'm going to get the data refreshed, and make a note for the sprint planning to fix this datatype.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the database in which the error is not showing contains only integer values in the column GROUP_INVOICE_NUMBER.That means the column values does not contain alphanumeric characters.Try like this:

```
select *
from GROUP
where GROUP_INVOICE_NUMBER = '4'
```

Comment: Adding to this while using where conditions on Varchar columns we cannot directly specify the value.Instead give it in single quotes.